# Problem with boost named_mutex hanging on Windows

Tags: boost

I have a user reporting that the following code in my application's main()
hangs unless he uses "Run as Adminstrator":

```
       ZTRACE_RUNTIME("Checking Mutex");
       bip::named_mutex dssMutex{ bip::open_or_create,
"DeepSkyStacker.Mutex.UniqueID.12354687" };
       bip::scoped_lock<bip::named_mutex> lk(dssMutex, bip::defer_lock);
       const bool firstInstance{ lk.try_lock() };
       ZTRACE_RUNTIME(" firstInstance: %s", firstInstance ? "true" :
"false");
```

The trace shows "Checking mutex" and then it all stops.

Is my code in error and if so what do I need to change? If not, how can I
determine what the problem is?

On a related issue: I think that this is C++ Exception safe, as the mutex
will be unlocked and deleted.

However, if a C exception occurs then how should I clean up?

Is the named_mutex persistent over reboots? If so, where is it held (in
case I need to do a manual cleanup).

Many thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in the code, but in the way your processes terminate. If you kill them or they crash, they may indefinitely "hold" the lock, even after termination.

There is no real solution as there [aren't (portable) robust named mutexes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bboost-interprocess%5d%20robust&searchOn=3).

Note that on Windows I seem to remember that the implementation has been made to detect when a reboot happened after the last lock was acquired, which breaks the lock for you. So, a reboot would always work.

In practice I would suggest using `try_lock` with a timeout (e.g. [`timed_lock` or `try_lock_until` etc.](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_mutex.html)). Then provide feedback to the user. To [force abandon the lock](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_mutex.html#idm31923-bb) you could have an explicit command line option, to be used by an appliciation admin that know what they're doing.